# Blender 2.93 - Material preview - objects are partially see through?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Using 2.93, rendering a Tractor.

In the viewport:

- in Rendered view (using cycles) the tractor looks fine
- in Solid view the tractor looks fine

the issue is in material preview mode.   I honestly don't know how to describe what I'm seeing other than the object seems partially transparent and objects sometimes draw in front of others which they are definitely 'behind' in a specific view.

Never seen this behavior before, any ideas?

Here's the cycles view (correct):

[image]

Here's the Solid view (correct):

[image]

Here's the material preview (incorrect):

[image]

Comment: Material preview uses an eevee-based, raster renderer to display your scene (instead of cycles raytrace renderer). This handles many things differently, especially anything transparency-related (this incudes the Blend Mode, even if the object has no transparency) Press Z and switch to rendered to preview to see your object peoperly. If you want to view it in eevee, first switch your renderer, then go into the material settings of the object and check if enabling/disabling "Backface culling" does anything. If the Blend Mode is set to alpha-blend, try the same thing with "Show Backface"

Comment: if Christophers comment doesn't help, please provide blend file, so we can tell you what the reason is and don't have to guess...

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Surely this must be a bug. I've never seen this behaviour before 2.93 and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Nvm I see that it's just because the model imported with Alpha Blend rather than Alpha Hashed. Not really sure about the difference but I see there's sorting issues with Alpha Blend in Eevee for some reason. Seems like a pretty critical issue given Material Preview view mode uses Eevee.

Comment: If you work with transparency in eevee enough, you see it all the time - eevee is not good with transparency through transparency, so something like a glass ball for example, confuses the renderer with regards to how it should show the "far side" of the object you're looking through (otherwise it would simply be invisible and seem as if you're looking at only "half" a glass ball). Because of this, the renderer tries to guess on what to cull to keep the idea of transparency somewhat convincing - it's just not very good at it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Christopher for the pointers.

As it turns out, all the materials I imported were set to Alpha-Blend mode.  All I did is change each of them to Alpha-Hash and viola, everything looks normal.  I did have one material which had Alpha set to 0 (so it disappeared in the viewport) but reset to 1.0 and there it is.