# Principled shader transmission parameter outer objects ignored and background images appears

Tags: materials

[image]

When material's transmission is edited I get a strange result like the outer white sphere is ignored and sky environment is see through from inside sphere.

Do you have any insight about this?

Comment: Probably duplication of https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228844/2214

Comment: Thank you very much for advices,I will see the link.